# Why is the real part of the permittivity the phase angle?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, speed-of-light, polarization, phase-velocity

The relative electric permittivity $\epsilon_r$ describes polarization inside a material due to electromagnetic waves (e.g., visible light passing a medium). I understand that the induced dipoles cannot follow the $\vec{E}$-vector of the electromagnetic field (light), so that there is a phase angle (a "delay"), whose actual value depends on the material's properties. These delayed dipoles re-emit radiation that interferes with the original electromagnetic wave and that is said to be the explanation for slowing down the speed of light inside a material. In addition, the original wave looses energy because of the displacement of charges inside the medium.

Because of these two effects (phase angle meaning slowing down and damping), the permittivity is described as a complex number ("complex numbers allow specification of magnitude and phase", found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity). This makes sense as a complex number $\epsilon$ can be written as

$$ \epsilon=|\epsilon|\cdot e^{-i \delta}$$

Naively, I would now assume that $\delta$ is the mentioned phase angle and $|\epsilon|$ is a number between 0 and 1 describing the damping. But instead the permittivity is written as

$$\epsilon = \epsilon' - i \epsilon ''$$

where the imaginary part $\epsilon ''$ describes the loss (in case of a metal $\epsilon '' = \frac{\sigma}{\omega}$ with $\sigma$ = conductivity) and the real part $\epsilon'$ is said to describe the phase. The latter is what I don't understand, because both equations combined give
$$
\epsilon = \epsilon' - i \epsilon '' = \left| \frac{D_0}{E_0} \right| \left( cos(\delta) + i \cdot sin(\delta) \right)
$$
so the phase angle $\delta$ is in both, real part and imaginary part. But why do we say then the real part (alone) describes the phase angle?

And even more confusing: In case of no loss (meaning the imaginary part is $0$), the permittivity would be real meaning that $\delta = 0$, and thus no reduced speed of light, which appears pretty strange... So what do I miss, what is actually the phase angle between original electromagnetic wave and induced polarisations, and why is that the real part of the permittivity?

Comment: I did not read your full question as I'm in a hurry, but my feeling is because you disregarded how this term is introduced into equations. Its not by itself, $\epsilon$ ***IS*** the exponent, ie ...$e^{i\epsilon}$, so after decomposition, you have a phase term (the real part $e^{i\epsilon'}$) and amplitude $e^{i i\epsilon''}=e^{-\epsilon''}$.

Comment: @José Andrade That would be a good explanation as we do the same with the complex index of refraction (which is also in the exponent of e.g. a planar wave). And $n$ is the sqrt of $\epsilon_r$ neglecting $\mu_r$. On the other hand, we have $\vec{D} = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \vec{E} = \epsilon_0 \vec{E} + \vec{P}$, where the permittivity is just multiplied to the E-vector.